# Firefox OS Hello world app works fine on simulator but displays black screen mobile device

Tags: firefox, screen, firefox-os

I am learning Firefox Os app development, I have created one app its simple app with some static text in it.
It works file on simulator but when I try to run it on my testing device ( Intex Cloud FX) it displays black screen.
I am not sure why it is happening. 
I have configured development evirinment on MAC OS.
Hope I get some tip for this problem, I have been looking all over the google but can't find anything.

Here is code of manifest file.

```
{
```

"name": "Hello",
  "description": "Hello World app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "128": "/img/icon-128.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "malkit singh",
    "url": "http://venturepact.com"
  }
}

and code of index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello World!</title>


</head>
```

hi

```
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was expecting something related to problem instead of down vote. :D

Comment: Have you already tried to adjust the launch path? Maybe check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Apps/Manifest#Path_handling

Comment: Yes I tested It, it seems to work fine. I tried removing / from path and then it created error. Actually app is working fine on simulator but doesn't work at all on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this through email. Add in your CSS file:

```
html, body {
  background: white;
}
```